# How do you set up iPhone Mobile Calls?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios

I have iPhone 6 (iOS 8.1), and I am trying to use a 2013 MacBook Air (OSX10.10) to call using the iPhone.

I am getting this error message

[image]

Now obviously I have checked that both devices are using the same iCloud account - of course they already were.

Has anyone else suffered a similar issue and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to find a fix for the issue I was having.

Under Facetime settings on my iPhone, Facetime was turned on, but it wasn't activated.

I had to turn off Facetime, switch it back on again and then activate it from another device.

It now works.